# Applications of Recurrence Relations - Find a Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Here's the question: 
"Find a recurrence relation for the number of bit strings
of length n that contain a pair of consecutive 0s."

1) The recurrence relation is $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + 2^{n-2}$. But when I put in 3 for n, I get 3. The two below are the only ones that I can think of

```
[0][0][1]
[1][0][0]
```

2) If the relation for this question is $a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + 2^{n-2}$, then how do I get that? I sort of understand $a(n-1)$, but how do I get $a(n-2)$ and especially $2^{n-2}$? Like, what am I looking for in the problem to where I can see that "Oh, I need this two recurrences and this other function that works like $2^{n}$?

Comment: To apply the recurrence relation as you propose for $n=3$, you need initial values for $a(2),a(1)$, but you've said nothing about how you got those initial values.

Comment: I got it by testing. a(1) = 0 because you cant make a pair with length of 1 and a(2) = 1 because only 1 pair of consecutive 0's can be made with length 2

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot $000.$
2. The recurrence relation becomes clear when you think of appending bits. There are three ways of making a bit string of length $n$ with a pair of consecutive $0$s.

First, take any bit string of length $n-2$ and append a pair of consecutive $0$s. There are $2^{n-2}$ of such strings.

Second, take any bit string of length $n-1$ with a pair of consecutive $0$s and append $1.$ There are $a(n-1)$ of such strings.

Third, take any bit string of length $n-2$ with a pair of consecutive $0$s and append  $10.$ There are $a(n-2)$ of such strings.

Edit:

The  last bit of a bit string of length $n$ with a pair of consecutive $00$s can be $0,1.$ If the last bit is $1,$ then the preceding $n-1$ bits must contain a pair of consecutive $00$s. There are $a(n-1)$ bit strings of length $n-1$ with a pair of consecutive $00$s.

If the last bit is $0,$ then the last two bits of the bit string of length $n$ with a pair of consecutive $00$s can be $00,10.$ If the last two bits are $00,$ then the preceding $n-2$ bits can be whatever. There are $2^{n-2}$ bit strings of length $n-2.$

If the last two bits are $10,$ then the preceding $n-2$ bits must contain a pair of consecutive $00$s. There are $a(n-2)$ bit strings of length $n-2$ with a pair of consecutive $00$s.

From this it follows that $a(n)=2^{n-2}+a(n-1)+a(n-2).$

Comment: I'm slowly understanding, but my slight hiccup is your conclusions. In your first case, you go from n - 2 to 2^(n-2); second case, n - 1 append 1 to a(n-1) and so on. My question, in short, is how do you know this fact that a(n-1) deals with n-1 length? Again, I think I'm close to understanding, but the conclusions are a little hazy. Also, if there are any videos that you know of that could help that would be great also

Comment: I edited my post, so I hope my conclusions are a little clearer. Sorry, I don't happen to know any videos that'd help. However, writing out all bit strings of length $n=4$ with a pair of consecutive $0$s and seeing everything adds up might help. At the very least, it helped me.